# Trouble with ul overflow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, haml

Here's the problem. I have one haml page with a list that looks like this: [image]

It's a list with elements formed by a div (left side) and an ul of buttons (right side). Here's the summarized code:

```
%li.rutinas-li{style: "overflow:visible"}
    %div{ style: "display: inline-block;" }
        = link_to ...
            ...
            %br
            %p ...
        %br
        %span
            = ...
            .thumbs-container
                =link_to ...
                     = icon('thumbs-up', ...)
                %strong ...
             .thumbs-container
                =link_to ...
                    = icon('thumbs-down', ...)
                %strong ...
            .thumbs-container
                =link_to ...
                    = icon('star', ...)
    %ul.pull-right.without-bullets.no-padding
        %li.inline-block= link_to ...
        %li.inline-block= link_to ...
        %li.inline-block= link_to ...
        %li.inline-block.dropdown
            %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle": "dropdown", type: "button"}
                = icon('share-alt', ...)
            %ul.dropdown-menu{style: "min-width:0"}
                %li{style: "padding: 15px"}
                    = link_to ...
                        = icon('envelope', ...}
                %li{style: "padding: 15px"}
                     = link_to ...
                         = icon('twitter', ...")
                 %li{style: "padding: 15px;"}
                      = link_to ...
                          = icon('facebook', ...)
```

I need the line 1 `{style: "overflow:visible"}` because the last ul is a dropdown that looks like this:
[image]
And if I remove it the dropdown is cropped. However, this css property causes also that when the screen is smaller ( a mobile phone, for example), the list is displayed like this:
[image]
And I would like it like this instead:
[image]
As the overflow is permitted, the list of buttons on the right are overflowing the parent and his white separators, it is kind of ugly. But if I remove `{style: "overflow:visible"}` the dropdown won't be visible when I click on it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just the width and height of your elements, you must change it if the device is smaller.

**Think responsive !** A great solution would be to create a media query and to place your buttons under your text.

If you don't want your ' li ' to have a too big height, you could also place differently your text so it could take the full width too.